# Convert pytorch pkl file to ptl file

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, pytorch-lightning

I've trained a classification model using pytorch and got the model in pkl format. I need to convert this file to ptl format to deploy in React Native platform. Is there any way to convert the pkl file to ptl or I need to train the classification model again in another way?

[image]